# XSL - Execute code if a node has a given node as parent

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML (simplified):

```
<node1>
    <node2>
        <node3>
        </node3>
    </node2>
</node1>
```

And I need to determine (using XSL) if node3 has a parent named node1 (not only the inmediate parent, so in the example node3 is a child of node1)

The following code is not working:

```
<xsl:if test="parent::node1">

</xsl:if>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**node3** is not a direct *child*, it is a *descendant*.  Use the *ancestor* axis instead, which selects all ancestors (parent, grandparent, etc.) of the current node.

http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp

```
<xsl:if test="ancestor::node1">

</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<xsl:if test="count(ancestor::node1)&gt;0">

</xsl:if>
```

You can omit the count if you like, it is not required. It can be useful when you are in a recursive structure to find the depth the current node is at.